# Set Azure Release Name Format another way?

Tags: azure, format, release

I want the release name to be something like:
Release-27-v1.0.0.0
In this way I will have an unique release name, including the application assembly version.

In Azure Classic Release, you can set the Release Name format through Options/General.
Eg "Release-$(Rev:r)", ie Release-27.

I can in a Powershell task set another one, eg:

```
$newReleaseName = "Release-...-$(assemblyVersion)"
Write-Host "##vso[release.updatereleasename]$newReleaseName"
```

I am able to include the $assemblyVersion from the build pipeline, through a file,
but I can't include the Rev number in some way in $newReleaseName.

It seems that I can use Rev through Release Name format and the assembly version through the powershell, but not combine them!?